# Fallback UPDATE statement in SQLite

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, t-sql

I want to run an UPDATE statement in SQLite which will be transformed to another UPDATE statement when no rows will be affected by the first one.
In t-sql I can simply write

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field1 = @FieldValue) 
   UPDATE Table WITH (ROWLOCK) 
   SET OtherField1 = @OtherField1Value,
       OtherField2 = @OtherField2Value,
          ...
   WHERE Field1 = @FieldValue
ELSE
   UPDATE Table WITH (ROWLOCK)
   SET OtherField1 = @OtherField1Value,
       OtherField2 = @OtherField2Value,
   ...
   WHERE Field2 = @FieldValue
```

However this syntax does not work in SQLite. Ideally, I would prefer something that

- Works in both SQLite and Microsoft SQL Server (we allow users to use any of those)
- Does not require to run 2 different statements (run first one and then if no rows are affected run the second one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `WITH (ROWLOCK)` equivalent in SQLite and also SQLite does not support variables or stored procedures.
This will do it:

```
UPDATE Table 
SET OtherField1 = :OtherField1Value,
    OtherField2 = :OtherField2Value,
          ...
WHERE Field1 = :FieldValue
   OR (
         Field2 = :FieldValue 
         AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE Field1 = :FieldValue)
      )
```

Replace `:value`s with the parameters that you want to pass.
This query works in SQLite and any other database (that I can think of) because it is written in standard SQL.

Comment: Amazing. For some reason I thought "NOT EXISTS" syntax will also not work in SQLite. Apparently it works. Thanks a lot!